# boost::multiprecision::powm differs from BigInteger#modPow in Java

Tags: java, c++, boost, amazon-cognito, srp-protocol

I am trying to reimplement SRP protocol for AWS Cognito in C++ with Boost and looking at Android implementation from Amazon.

I faced an issue where `powm` function with the same argument returns different results in Java and in C++. Below are real variables to reproduce.

```
base = -60069516222067934465050534050924735913259123336604003695277708341824332895413979944668873920813978546728706494838542031539374089411576323557683032079456300479576399686088457834323998789559447280306593096633556722918700757880790576568543160534527724248702686289473589204691773279466673778290317667494679021095759596587143108565755917479750768759519224411507201300590256025341023717379667034891896621559345748879219694808586783746072343055239350628677886152249850829448959449884027507137715617906830580188376921330347491783964930384160916882168844833991645809121747349916283613126899731249980617076083650399040055004037242145087844202129219022561806749382444723981250548071098932686072865117465590944246091868534389708960372902345012028512996301150892770425867448873457573540209290963648133766450038070701366521974251173331552053367466421294567346255207594293174647572109245024389844295595423148975431938500850550834122854589221010198699007954971109000609845414067610786404346462923082635417069420150663

exp = 146462318780050704398491824679577877249637357233997958820955798606849034089055435560888738746472653803474347785215052176587544928236521681250726410243117146638424272590451021577470339456543664816801048455555325077949491666342480646917362501726371391429930610071051177605862191601117139467049042192421315075925

mod = 5809605995369958062791915965639201402176612226902900533702900882779736177890990861472094774477339581147373410185646378328043729800750470098210924487866935059164371588168047540943981644516632755067501626434556398193186628990071248660819361205119793693985433297036118232914410171876807536457391277857011849897410207519105333355801121109356897459426271845471397952675959440793493071628394122780510124618488232602464649876850458861245784240929258426287699705312584509625419513463605155428017165714465363094021609290561084025893662561222573202082865797821865270991145082200656978177192827024538990239969175546190770645685893438011714430426409338676314743571154537142031573004276428701433036381801705308659830751190352946025482059931306571004727362479688415574702596946457770284148435989129632853918392117997472632693078113129886487399347796982772784615865232621289656944284216824611318709764535152507354116344703769998514148343807
```

Java (all variables are BigInteger):

```
BigInteger x = base.modPow(exp, mod);

x: 1230568615184131985239346694446825655892733339973705775794155717290665406519709910407387531042376274634783342677355212818101752559959454003565957987129773506359982415765799964505534198533317147147330259998210157489219128947077927164476066764792878755295287228542190650053716328463274779372118557925988198416352338648543137326490077853579150463484865391556678099929526143587731521332343634512569891817217753866541107231323752824752313183429346607264168653584884607177140562811376873489718089411252979981686946488318076743666882294457424784508392043142317072588165582750606934742360106685332345292776496954791945874043489368333919203276279792510478642311867043688320756550623809890002329790942184110903137973601678472100031271022409063644536472615014574455126844337240082531858482475302880382827055687831445880729409121007713054522708302456617762637870271318479897319132492452505220079651903923918555883332563223829904474269679
```

C++ (all variables are cpp_int):

```
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

cpp_int x = boost::multiprecision::powm(base, exp, mod);

x: -4579037380185826077552569271192375746283878886929194757908745165489070771371280951064707243434963306512590067508291165509941977240791016094644966500737161552804389172402247576438447445983315607920171366436346240703967500042993321496343294440326914938690146068493927582860693843413532757085272719931023651481057868870562196029311043255777746995941406453914719852746433297205761550296050488267940232801270478735923542645526706036493471057499911819023531051727699902448278950652228281938299076303212383112334662802243007282226780266765148417574473754679548198402979499450050043434832720339206644947192678591398824771642404069677795227150129546165836101259287493453710816453652618811430706590859521197756692777588674473925450788908897507360190889864673841119575752609217687752289953513826752471091336430166026751963668992122173432876639494526155021977994961302809759625151724372106098630112631228588798233012140546168609674074128
```

Where is the issue?

UPDATE:

Python `pow(base,exp,mod)` returns the same as Java.
Looks like a bug in Boost, or I am using it in wrong way?

Comment: It's not a bug **and** you're not using it the wrong way. It's just implementation defined differences. Your expectations were the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a documented difference of how signed modulo is implemented.

Try `-3 mod 5` for fun.

As an immediate workaround, you can select a different backend (like gmp):
**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd51618126e68734)</kbd>**

### Analysis

There is a slight inconsistency between the cpp_int backend and the GMP backend, e.g. testing:

```
----
CppInt: -3 mod  5 = consistently -3
----
MpzInt: -3 mod  5 = -3
MpzInt: -3 powm 5 = 2
MpzInt: -3 mypm 5 = -3
mismatch
----
CppInt: -3 mod  17 = consistently -3
----
MpzInt: -3 mod  17 = -3
MpzInt: -3 powm 17 = 14
MpzInt: -3 mypm 17 = -3
mismatch
```

As you can see Boost chose to be consistent for its own types.

Note that the Boost approach seems to be objectively better because it makes sure that the **identity** `(a/b)*b + powm(a,1,b)` always holds.

### Fix

As a simple fix, just add the divisor if the return value is negative:

```
template <class T> T my_powm(const T& a, const T& p, const T& c) {
    using std::abs; // summon the god of ADL
    T r = powm(a, p, c);
    return r<0? r + abs(c) : r;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6446a4865072b9b0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

template <class T> T my_powm(const T& a, const T& p, const T& c) {
    using std::abs; // summon the god of ADL
    T r = powm(a, p, c);
    return r<0? r + abs(c) : r;
}

int main() {
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int
        base{"-60069516222067934465050534050924735913259123336604003695277708341824332895413979944668873920813978546728706494838542031539374089411576323557683032079456300479576399686088457834323998789559447280306593096633556722918700757880790576568543160534527724248702686289473589204691773279466673778290317667494679021095759596587143108565755917479750768759519224411507201300590256025341023717379667034891896621559345748879219694808586783746072343055239350628677886152249850829448959449884027507137715617906830580188376921330347491783964930384160916882168844833991645809121747349916283613126899731249980617076083650399040055004037242145087844202129219022561806749382444723981250548071098932686072865117465590944246091868534389708960372902345012028512996301150892770425867448873457573540209290963648133766450038070701366521974251173331552053367466421294567346255207594293174647572109245024389844295595423148975431938500850550834122854589221010198699007954971109000609845414067610786404346462923082635417069420150663"},
        exp{"146462318780050704398491824679577877249637357233997958820955798606849034089055435560888738746472653803474347785215052176587544928236521681250726410243117146638424272590451021577470339456543664816801048455555325077949491666342480646917362501726371391429930610071051177605862191601117139467049042192421315075925"},
        mod{"5809605995369958062791915965639201402176612226902900533702900882779736177890990861472094774477339581147373410185646378328043729800750470098210924487866935059164371588168047540943981644516632755067501626434556398193186628990071248660819361205119793693985433297036118232914410171876807536457391277857011849897410207519105333355801121109356897459426271845471397952675959440793493071628394122780510124618488232602464649876850458861245784240929258426287699705312584509625419513463605155428017165714465363094021609290561084025893662561222573202082865797821865270991145082200656978177192827024538990239969175546190770645685893438011714430426409338676314743571154537142031573004276428701433036381801705308659830751190352946025482059931306571004727362479688415574702596946457770284148435989129632853918392117997472632693078113129886487399347796982772784615865232621289656944284216824611318709764535152507354116344703769998514148343807"};

    std::cout << my_powm(base, exp, mod) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
1230568615184131985239346694446825655892733339973705775794155717290665406519709910407387531042376274634783342677355212818101752559959454003565957987129773506359982415765799964505534198533317147147330259998210157489219128947077927164476066764792878755295287228542190650053716328463274779372118557925988198416352338648543137326490077853579150463484865391556678099929526143587731521332343634512569891817217753866541107231323752824752313183429346607264168653584884607177140562811376873489718089411252979981686946488318076743666882294457424784508392043142317072588165582750606934742360106685332345292776496954791945874043489368333919203276279792510478642311867043688320756550623809890002329790942184110903137973601678472100031271022409063644536472615014574455126844337240082531858482475302880382827055687831445880729409121007713054522708302456617762637870271318479897319132492452505220079651903923918555883332563223829904474269679
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much, @sehe, your `my_powm` is really working solution!
But.. Just for curiosity, does it mean that other implementations, at least in Java and Python, are wrong, as they are breaking mentioned equation?

Comment: No they just have a different contract. Boost is staying consistent with the behaviour of integer modulo as specified in c++11 (before that, signed modulo was implementation defined even in C and C++)

Comment: OK, I see, it's interesting to check in some mathematical sources, what is the right answer, because I am not sure that modulo operator is so ambiguous.. I'll mark your answer as right after several tests. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation is a good resource. Processors have some real life constraints to deal with, and it will be good if programmers know what they are. It's mistake to assume learning computing is the same as learning maths. It's important to learn both. [There's a strong relation, and you can _implement_ arithmetic operations. However, there is no reason for processors to _natively_ adhere to the laws of, say, number theory. Just increment 2^31-1 on a 32bit CPU for example.]

Comment: Yes, I understand, that in real world magnitudes of variables from my example are absolutely unusal!! I think it's impossible to check such powm results with paper and pencil)) In computational real world, of course, most important are stable results, efficient resources usage. I just didn't expect that results of such operation can be different. Saying frankly, I still don't understand, because, I suppose, there is not a big difference in cpu/mem usage among that implementations. But I am not so strong to argue here))